# Spectral decomposition of symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, dense-matrix

What is a good direct method to compute the spectral decomposition / Schur decomposition / singular decomposition of a symmetric matrix?

"Direct" means as in LU decomposition, Cholesky decomposition, or Golub's SVD algorithm, in contrast to iterative methods.

You can, of course, apply the aforementioned algorithm of Golub, but I guess that would be breaking a butterfly on a wheel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to the QR algorithm, the [divide and conquer method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide-and-conquer_eigenvalue_algorithm) is also worth mentioning. It is applicable to symmetric tridiagonal matrices, but any matrix can be reduced to such a form via the Lanczos method*. It hinges on the observation that a tridiagonal matrix is, up to a rank 1 perturbation, a block diagonal matrix. One can then find the eigendecomposition of the sub-blocks (in parallel!) and glue them back together using a clever trick. Of course, finding the eigenvalues of the blocks must be done with the QR method as Federico alludes to.

However, you've asked for a direct method -- both QR and divide and conquer are iterative methods. Well, there is no direct method akin to the LU decomposition to find the eigendecomposition of a matrix of dimension greater than 5, there are *only* iterative methods. If such a direct method existed, one could find the zeros of an arbitrarily high-degree polynomial as an algebraic function of the coefficients, which Galois told us is impossible. The [Golub-Kahan SVD algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition#Calculating_the_SVD) is also iterative.

Comment: The distinction between direct and iterative seems quite ill-posed, indeed. I took it as "no Arnoldi".

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this to me.

@FedericoPolini: I take non-iterative as 'produces the result for an n x n matrix in f(n) steps, where f(n) is some function'. See the contrast between LU decomposition and Jacobi iteration.

But even if one accepts this: Some recommend applying a Jacobi iteration after an LU-decomposition based solver. So one may regard this as one algorithm of two phases.

Comment: I don't think your argument is strictly correct: first, using Galois theory there can be shown not to exist a general *radical* function of the coefficients, which is a very special form of an algebraic function. Second, I don't see how a direct method for the decomposition would necessarily lead to a radical function to obtain the roots for the coefficients: it depends a bit on what you mean by non-iterative evaluation, but if you want to allow using sin, sqrt, log etc there exist non-iterative ways to express the roots of a polynomial in its coefficients (at least for degree 5).

Comment: E.g. for the quintic there is a general expression in *transcendental functions* of the coefficients that can be evaluated as floating point numbers in constant time. This is desribed explicitly here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bring_radical#The_Hermite.E2.80.93Kronecker.E2.80.93Brioschi_characterization and here: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/QuinticEquation.html

Answer (score 1):

The [implicit (Francis) QR iteration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_algorithm), with several additional tricks, is the standard algorithm. I suggest you to check a book such as Watkins' *The Matrix Eigenvalue Problem* for details; this is a classical topic.

(I find it unusual that you are familiar with Golub's SVD but not with QR - the two methods are similar and usually taught together).